# What is the difference between 1:5 and c(1,2,3,4,5)?

Tags: r, vector

I'm very confused with the data structure concepts in R (those are much more easy to understand in SAS).

Is there any difference between  `x <- 1:5` and `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)`?
From the environment window, I know that one is `int` and the other is `num`.

Comment: `:` is a function for creating integer sequences.  Both vectors are numeric, but the latter is numeric double.  Double is numeric, integer is integer and also numeric.  Integers generally make operations faster.

Comment: If you wanted to force the second option to be integer type instead of numeric, you could do `x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)` or `x <- as.integer(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`.

Comment: i believe sas has one data structure so I imagine that it would be easier

Answer (score 4):

`x` and `y` below are not quite identical because they have different *storage modes*, as you discovered by using `str(x)` and `str(y)`.  In my experience, this distinction is unimportant 99% of the time; R uses fairly loose typing, and integers will automatically be promoted to double (i.e. double-precision floating point) when necessary. Integers and floating point values below the maximum integer value (`.Machine$integer.max`) can be converted back and forth without loss of information.  (Integers do take slightly less space to store, and can be slightly faster to compute with as @RichardScriven comments above.)

If you want to create an integer vector, append `L` as below ... or use `as.integer()` as suggested in comments above.

```
x <- 1:5
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
z <- c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L)
all.equal(x,y) ## test for _practical_ equivalence: TRUE
identical(x,y) ## FALSE
identical(x,z) ## TRUE
```

`storage.mode()` and `class()` may also be useful, as well as `is.integer()`, `is.double()`, `as.integer()`, `as.double()`, `is.numeric()` ...